# How to do Soundcloud Auth Dance in JS with a Redirect_URL that has GET Params

Tags: oauth-2.0, soundcloud

** I am currently implementing fancy URLs to see if these 'solves' this. eg /me/soundcloudconnect rather than index.php?c=me&a=soundcloudconnect via mod_rewrite **

I have been using the Soundcloud JS SDK and SC.Connect() etc function(s) which automates much of the Auth process. I have been using a Normal html file: sc.html which worked fine and allowed me to get /me/ and /me/tracks etc.

However I now realise? that I will need to perform Auth myself as I need to add a State variable as documented below, so that it prepends these params to the end of the Redirect_URI.

http://groups.google.com/group/soundcloudapi/browse_thread/thread/7bddbc296f3b80af

The URL that I am trying to redirect back to is:

index.php?c=me&a=soundcloudconnect

which is the 'me' controller and 'soundcloudconnect' action.

So could someone please point me in the right direction?

Either I want to be able to use SC.Connect() etc (but also be able to get and save Token) as well as redirect back to the URI above

Or, I need to do the same thing (Auth and store token) but not using SC.Connect() but normal JS instead.

I read that Soundcloud Developer support is via Stackoverflow - so hopefully someone can help?

The normal HTML file with working SC Auth: 
http://socialartist.co/sc.html

The dynamic page which does not work with SC Auth:
http://socialartist.co/index.php?c=me&a=soundcloudconnect#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is probably that those query parameters are interfering with the original url. E.g. http://www.soundcloud.com/register/?token=blagha23412&redirect_uri=http://anydomain.com/index.php?c=me&a=soundcloudconnect

How would SoundCloud distinguish between your parameters and its parameters? You might be able to wrap the redirect_uri value in quotes.

An alternative might be to use the path as your parameters. E.g. http://anydomain.com/index.php/me/soundcloudconnect and then you should be able to grab whatever you need out of the path on your server.

Comment: I believe you have to UrlEnclode the parameters, pass them into OAuth2 via State parameter, and then strip them back out. Not so easy when you are using the Soundcloud JS API as it does a lot for you.

Comment: I could implement fancy URLs so that ?c=me&a=soundcloudconnect would have a url of /me/soundcloudconnect - which may work. But this URL dictates the MVC structure of the application, eg controller=me, action=soundcloudconnect.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions though @ emil10001

Comment: Yes, good point about encoding the URL. I have no idea what SoundCloud allows via it's API/authentication. You could use an htaccess file to translate the path after a certain endpoint into query parameters. That way you just write one little regexp that takes care of this for you and both sides are happy.

Comment: It *should be fairly straight forward, I am just a bit a JS/JQuery API newbie.. The article above was answered from a Soundcloud Developer hence they must be a way to get this to work..  To be honest I need to get at the security tokens anyway so will need to go back to basics and do the Auth dance via JS step by step.. Thanks for your suggestions..

Comment: *get at the security tokens to store them, not do something *bad lol

Comment: So, my initial answer was what you ended up using?

Comment: lol "I could implement fancy URLs so that ?c=me&a=soundcloudconnect would have a url of /me/soundcloudconnect - which may work. But this URL dictates the MVC structure of the application, eg controller=me, action=soundcloudconnect" -- had a proof-of-concept of this for years, but if you the credit for the "answer" fill you boots..

Answer (score 0):

** SOLVED!! **

If you need to pass parameters to SC connect/auth then the only way to do this is to setup fancy urls via mod_rewrite.

There 'seems' to be another method here, but you need to be doing the Auth in 2 steps and not via SC.Connect.

http://groups.google.com/group/soundcloudapi/browse_thread/thread/7bddbc296f3b80af

I was trying to get URL_redirect to work with:

index.php?c=me&a=soundcloudconnect

But in the End just used Fancy URLs which worked

http://socialartist.co/me/soundcloudconnect